# Why 3 factorial is there?

Tags: combinatorics

An urn contains $4$ red marbles and $8$ black marbles. What is the probability that exactly $2$ red marbles are drawn before the third black marble  if the marbles are drawn without replacement?

I happened to get the correct answer, which is:

$\left(\frac{4}{12}\right)\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)\left(\frac{6}{8}\right)3!$

but somehow I do not understand why we should multiply all the numbers with $3!$

Can someone explain to me?

Thank you!

Comment: Permutations; the first and second black can occur in between the two red marbles, rbbrb, bbrrb, rrbbb, brbrb, brrbb, rbrbb you see?

Comment: yes, but that makes 4 right?

Comment: There are six ways.

Comment: There must be $2$ red and $2$ black marbles before the third black marble.  The positions of the red marbles can be selected in $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways.

Comment: oops my bad! Yes I understand now thank you!

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the rationale would be for $3!$ rather than $4\choose 2$

Comment: Another way to look at that. The last result is $b$. Before that we choose four times. We have ${4\choose 2}=6$ possibilities to place the $b$ results. $6$ happens to be $3!$. To me the ${4\choose 2}$ version is more natural.

Comment: I'm equally mystified as to how you ended up with $3!$ there. Just an incredibly lucky guess? Or is that just the answer in the solution set, and you wrote something that gets the same numeric result in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, the first five marbles are two reds and three blacks and these come in an order such that the last one is black.

Out of the $12\choose 5$ ways to pick $5$ marbles, there are ${4\choose 2}{8\choose 3}$ ways to pick $2$ reds and $3$ blacks. So the probability of drawing two reds and three blacks (in any order) is
$$ \frac{{4\choose 2}{8\choose 3}}{12\choose 5}=\frac{14}{33}.$$
However, the probability that the last of such five marbles is one of the three blacks, is $\frac 35$. Hence we have to multiply by that:
$$ \frac{14}{33}\cdot\frac35=\frac{14}{55}.$$